# Why it use client.set/get instead of Object property?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

All.

I have a question is socket.io.
In Socket.io, it provides socket.set/get method to store and retrieve socket related value. it seems useful but i have a question on it.

instead of using socket.set(key,value). I think Object property can be alternative solution like this "socket[key] = value"

is there any special benefit to user socket.set/get instead of Object property?

like cluster wide replication etc.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: it's generally unsafe to use objects as maps. Key like `__proto__` or `hasOwnProperty` may cause errors. Also when object is used for something more than storing key-value data there is a chance to override some important property. What about replication, I'm pretty sure it doesn't

Comment: Usually libraries provide set() methods when they perform some logic associated with assigning a value. If you assign the value directly you might bypass such logic.

Comment: @vkurchatkin thanx for the comment. So is there any recommendation or library in using MAP in javascript? (not asking about socket.set)

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed socket.io source code.

internally set/get uses MemStore, it stores value to Object property.
and if it use RedisStore. the setted value are stored in the Redis.

So the value can be shared by another node.js instance by using Redis.